# Parse JSON-like markup

Tags: php, regex

honestly i don't know what markup is this (i would like to know if this markup have a name). What is easyest way to parse structures like this? i have a lot of them in txt file.

```
unlockType BirthdayCake {
       // Don't delete
    commonName      "Birthday Cake"
    autoTag
    category        Item
    path            models/
    timedExclusive  1
    descSymbol      BirthdayCakeDesc
    dispSymbol      BirthdayCakeDisp
    flairCfg        "Cake/Idle.aaf mat_BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.0666  /moveVelThresh 10.0 /animEaseTime 1.0 /zOffRobot 2.7 /rotX 20.0 /zSpinDef bone_spinA 80.0"
    //OnInspectOrUnlock Menus previewInit Cake/Idle.aaf BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8 /rotSpeed 30 /pos 3.5 0 1 /scaleMult 1.0
    property        BirthdaySpirit          10
}
```

Comment: You could try exploding on tabs, not very efficient though :(

Comment: Looks like it's separated by tabs/spaces, and entries are divided by newlines. Were it just numbers and strings without spaces, it'd be OK. Problem will be the strings with quotes, kinda tricky to match with regex..

Comment: why do people insist on creating their own non-standard markup formats when so many good standards already exist?? It would be worth knowing where it came from, as there might be a perfectly good parser for it. It looks a lot like it might be program code, but I don't recognise the language. I'm really curious where you're getting it from -- how come the people supplying it to you can't tell you what it is?

Comment: do you have any more samples?

Comment: Would you be doing 1 at a time, or are there multiple of these in one string?

Comment: I am writing a parser, I hope I am alone. Would hate to waste the effort only to post it as second.

Comment: Also, are there specific bits of data you want to get out of it, or do you just want to get the whole thing into an array? ie what's the ultimate goal here? Without more samples, it's hard to know what the possible formats can be for the various fields, or whether there can be other fields, etc. There's too many variables. But if you're only after one or two specific data points, and they're always going to be consistent, then it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: i apologize but this it not "mine" format, this is format from some game, i'm just trying to count things from this game to make statistics. Their parser is obviously proprietary and written on C++

Comment: Ah, I was expecting it to be some kind of language to interface with Advanced Authoring Format, but games typically have their own parsers.

Comment: @MightyPork Thought I'd let you know I've also written one - afraid I didn't spot your comment until I posted my answer... still, multiple solutions won't hurt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You have to feed into it only the insides of the {} tags, and you get an array that respects the string quotes etc.

Unlike the other answer, it takes care of `"text with quotes"` and accepts both spaces, tabs and mixed for formatting.

```
$a = <<<EOT
    commonName      "Birthday Cake"
    autoTag
    category        Item
    path            models/
    timedExclusive  1
    descSymbol      BirthdayCakeDesc
    dispSymbol      BirthdayCakeDisp
    flairCfg        "Cake/Idle.aaf mat_BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.0666  /moveVelThresh 10.0 /animEaseTime 1.0 /zOffRobot 2.7 /rotX 20.0 /zSpinDef bone_spinA 80.0"
    //OnInspectOrUnlock Menus previewInit Cake/Idle.aaf BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8 /rotSpeed 30 /pos 3.5 0 1 /scaleMult 1.0
    property        BirthdaySpirit          10
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $a);

$parsed = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $chars = str_split($line);

    $quoteOpen = false;

    $lastField = "";

    $lineFields = array();

    foreach($chars as $c) {
        if($c == '"') {
            if($quoteOpen) {
                $quoteOpen = false;
                $lineFields[] = $lastField;
            } else {
                $quoteOpen = true;
            }
            $lastField = "";
            continue;
        }

        if(preg_match("/\\s/", $c) === 0) {
            $lastField .= $c;
        } else {
            if($lastField != "" && !$quoteOpen) {
                $lineFields[] = $lastField;
                $lastField = "";
            } else {
                if(!$lastField == "") {
                    $lastField .= $c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($lastField != "") {
        $lineFields[] = $lastField;
    }

    $parsed[] = $lineFields;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($parsed); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => commonName
            [1] => Birthday Cake
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => autoTag
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => category
            [1] => Item
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => path
            [1] => models/
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => timedExclusive
            [1] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => descSymbol
            [1] => BirthdayCakeDesc
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => dispSymbol
            [1] => BirthdayCakeDisp
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => flairCfg
            [1] => Cake/Idle.aaf mat_BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.0666  /moveVelThresh 10.0 /animEaseTime 1.0 /zOffRobot 2.7 /rotX 20.0 /zSpinDef bone_spinA 80.0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => //OnInspectOrUnlock
            [1] => Menus
            [2] => previewInit
            [3] => Cake/Idle.aaf
            [4] => BirthdayCake<
            [5] => /scale
            [6] => 1.5
            [7] => /animation
            [8] => Cake/Idle.aaf
            [9] => 0
            [10] => looping
            [11] => 0.8
            [12] => /rotSpeed
            [13] => 30
            [14] => /pos
            [15] => 3.5
            [16] => 0
            [17] => 1
            [18] => /scaleMult
            [19] => 1.0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => property
            [1] => BirthdaySpirit
            [2] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: seems like your solution works the best (in case i cut off comments myself), thank you!

Comment: You can check if the first element in an array starts with //, and if so, ignore it..

Comment: I had comment cleaning/triming function even before i asked this question (and made function from your reply). Anyway, thank you! you saved my time.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = "unlockType BirthdayCake {
       // Don't delete
    commonName      \"Birthday Cake\"
    autoTag
    category        Item
    path            models/
    timedExclusive  1
    descSymbol      BirthdayCakeDesc
    dispSymbol      BirthdayCakeDisp
    flairCfg        \"Cake/Idle.aaf mat_BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.0666  /moveVelThresh 10.0 /animEaseTime 1.0 /zOffRobot 2.7 /rotX 20.0 /zSpinDef bone_spinA 80.0\"
    //OnInspectOrUnlock Menus previewInit Cake/Idle.aaf BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8 /rotSpeed 30 /pos 3.5 0 1 /scaleMult 1.0
    property        BirthdaySpirit          10
}

unlockType PetFish3 {
        commonName              \"Lionfish\"
        autoTag
        category                Pet
        path                    flair/
        descSymbol              PetFish3Desc
        dispSymbol              PetFish3Disp
        flairCfg                \"pet flair/PetFishes/PetFish3.amf mat_PetFishes< /scale 1.1 /animation flair/PetFishes/idle3.aaf 0 looping 0.45 /moveAnim flair/PetFishes/fly1.aaf 1 looping 1.62  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.045 /moveVelThresh 8.0 /animEaseTime 0.45 /zOffRobot 2.6 /rotX 15.0 /moveSlew 0.05 /turnToMove 230\"
}
";

function parseThis($text)
{
    $types = array();
    preg_match_all('#(unlockType [^\{]+{.+?\n\s*})#s',$text,$matches);
    foreach($matches[1] as $str)
    {
        $typeName = preg_replace('#^[^ ]+ ([^ ]+).*#s','$1',$str);
        $contents = preg_split('#(\r?\n)+#',$str);
        $contents = array_map('trim',$contents);
        array_pop($contents);
        array_shift($contents);
        $data = array();
        foreach($contents as $line)
        {
            if(substr($line,0,2)=='//') continue;
            $parts = preg_split("#(\t+|\s{3,})#",$line);
            $title = array_shift($parts);
            $partC = count($parts);
            $data[$title] = $partC==1 ? $parts[0] : ($partC==0 ? '' : $parts);
        }
        $types[$typeName] = $data;
    }
    return $types;
}
$types = parseThis($str);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($types,true).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [BirthdayCake] => Array
        (
            [commonName] => "Birthday Cake"
            [autoTag] => 
            [category] => Item
            [path] => models/
            [timedExclusive] => 1
            [descSymbol] => BirthdayCakeDesc
            [dispSymbol] => BirthdayCakeDisp
            [flairCfg] => "Cake/Idle.aaf mat_BirthdayCake< /scale 1.5 /animation Cake/Idle.aaf 0 looping 0.8  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.0666  /moveVelThresh 10.0 /animEaseTime 1.0 /zOffRobot 2.7 /rotX 20.0 /zSpinDef bone_spinA 80.0"
            [property] => Array
                (
                    [0] => BirthdaySpirit
                    [1] => 10
                )

        )

    [PetFish3] => Array
        (
            [commonName] => "Lionfish"
            [autoTag] => 
            [category] => Pet
            [path] => flair/
            [descSymbol] => PetFish3Desc
            [dispSymbol] => PetFish3Disp
            [flairCfg] => "pet flair/PetFishes/PetFish3.amf mat_PetFishes< /scale 1.1 /animation flair/PetFishes/idle3.aaf 0 looping 0.45 /moveAnim flair/PetFishes/fly1.aaf 1 looping 1.62  /followDist 3.0 /moveSlew 0.045 /moveVelThresh 8.0 /animEaseTime 0.45 /zOffRobot 2.6 /rotX 15.0 /moveSlew 0.05 /turnToMove 230"
        )

)
```

**Rough Explanation**

- Use `preg_match_all` to find each block (unlockType someRandomText { .... })
- Loop through each result of `preg_match_all` (each block) to parse the blocks individually

  - Split the contents of the `{..}` by newlines and then map each result to `trim()` to remove any leading and trailing spaces/tabs

    - Split each line by 3 or more spaces (as proper tabs don't seem to have been used)
    - use the first result of the split as the key of our array, then push the rest of the split into the value

Comment: I would make the 'unlockType' matcher an agnostic type declaration token parser, also replace the `\t` with `\s+` just in case.

Comment: It's nice that you _solved_ his issue but I don't see how this helps the community much. You should consider explaining what strategies you used when solving this and why.

Comment: uh.. OK, looks like your answer was both faster AND better. Well I tried atleast..

Comment: @Flosculus I've removed the explicit 'unlockType' match, but can't see where I'm using a `\t` without accounting for `\s` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've attempted to explain my methods, though whether I've actually explained myself is another matter

Comment: Just to let you know, string with many subsequent spaces will break it. My method takes care of quotes around strings, it doesn't blindly split by groups of them. It's not as efficient and neat, but this wont be a problem for it.

Comment: `#^[^\{]+{.+?\n\s*\t*}#s` It uses a tab at the end.  Infact, you don't need `\t` because `\s` includes tabs